# Remote login on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login-screen, remote-login

On Ubuntu 13.10 in Login screen there was an option for Remote Login.Where is this option in Ubuntu 14.04?How can I enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install remote-login-service

```
sudo apt-get install remote-login-service
```